# Why isn't the if statement working?

Tags: java, boolean, conditional-statements, palindrome

I was trying to solve a problem of Project Euler with Java. The Problem 4.

http://projecteuler.net/problem=4

It said I had to find the largest palindrome made from the product of two 3-digit numbers.

So here is the code (just the part that isn't working) :

```
public class Problem4PE {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        int result = 0;
        Integer output = 0;

        for (int i = 100; i < 1000; i++) {
            for (int j = 100; j < 1000; j++) {
                output = i*j;
                String strout = output.toString();
                StringBuilder stb = new StringBuilder();

                char[] chrout = strout.toCharArray();
                for (int x = 0; x < chrout.length; x++) {
                    stb.append(chrout[x]);
                }
                StringBuilder stres = new StringBuilder("");
                for (int k = chrout.length-1; k > -1 ; k--) {
                    stres.append(chrout[k]);
                }
                String stbb = stb.toString();
                String string = stres.toString();
                Boolean bool = stbb.equals(string);
                if (bool){
                    result = output;
                }

            }
        }
        System.out.println(result);
    }
}
```

So aboves output comes out : 580085
But when I submit it, it shows incorrect. I do not understand why. So could you please tell me whether the problem is in code, or I had a mistake in understanding the question.

Comment: You could do much more to reduce the test case and figure out where it is failing.

Comment: Here's a big hint: add a line that prints `output` any time `bool` is true.  (Redirect the program's output to a file, since it's likely to be pretty big.)  I'm betting that if you do this and look over the results, you'll figure out why it isn't working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
if (bool && output > result) { // a second if condition.
  result = output;
}
```

It gives me the correct answer.

Answer (score 4):

Your code skips over the largest product.

`result` isn't guaranteed to increase between two iterations of your `for` loops, so the final value of `result` isn't the largest.